# How can I tell what referrer address my server side app is using

Tags: c#, youtube, ip

This seems like a simple question. I'm using a server-side app written in C# to do a simple api key connection to youtube from a Windows Server 2008 server. When I run it without an ip referer restriction it works fine. So I set up an ip referer restriction. I ran ipconfig on my server and used the main ip address listed, and I got an ipreferer blocked error. I also tried the other ip addresses listed. I've included a screenshot of my ipconfig with notes.

So I know the program is passing youtube some referer ip, and it's not the right one. How can I tell what the referer ip it is passing?

[image: A screenshot of my ipconfig]

The code is below:

```
/*
*/
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: search by keyword.
    /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
    /// See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted
    ///
    /// Set ApiKey to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps tab of
    ///   https://cloud.google.com/console
    /// Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Search
    {
        List<string> HTMLText = new List<string>();
        Boolean openDiv = true;
        string mainVideoTarget = "main_video";
        string menuDiv = "video_menu_images";
        string thumbnailDiv = "thumb";
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                new Search().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "API_KEY_HERE",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Id = "CHANNEL_ID_HERE";

            // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();


       //a bunch of stuff down here to read the data from youtube 
       //write it into an html file which I left out because it's irrelevant
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I am not using ASP.NET. I'm using a console application run on its own.

Comment: USe Fiddler (if it is HTTP/HTTPS traffic) or some lower level traffic sniffer (like WireShark) to see what request is actually sent...

Comment: if the server is behind any kind of router the ip returned by ipconfig is going to be your internal ip address not your external ip address

Answer (score 0):

`ipconfig` is returning the internal IP address. Try a site like http://whatismyip.com and use the IP address that site returns as the Referer address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and suggestions, especially pointing out that the ip from ipconfig is not what the router is passing. I know about whatsmyip but I wasn't 100% sure if that's the same ip that a console app would be using. Turns out it was. I was able to find the ip passed by running this simple little script:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest htwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[any url that can get an http connection]");
            WebResponse response = htwr.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

One of the variables returned is REMOTE_ADDR which is what I was looking for.